# XSS in Tinymce Package

Tags: tinymce, xss, richtext

I'm using [@tinymce/tinymce-react](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0y6b.png) Editor but I'm facing XSS issues like user can type JS and HTML like inputs and so on.

I have tried to configure it as in here

```js
      <Editor
        apiKey={PackagesKeysConfigs.TINY_API_KEY}
        value={value}
        init={{
          height: 300,
          max_height: 400,
          menubar: !disabled,
          language: 'ar',
          directionality: 'rtl',
          // resize: 'both',
          // Footer Target
          statusbar: false,
          branding: false,
          elementpath: false,
          // element_format: 'html',
          // encoding: 'xml',
          invalid_elements: 'script, input',
          entities: '20,>,<,<,160,nbsp,162,cent,8364,euro,163,pound',
          entity_encoding: 'raw',
          plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
          ],
          toolbar:
            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
            alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
            bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
        }}
        onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
      />
```

But the rendered HTML doesn't escape the chars like >, < and so on, `I need to escape them , because I'm parsing the saved HTML somewhere else.`

For Example:
when i save and parse the scripts runs like this
[image]

Here is the result

[image]

Any clue?
Thanks in advance/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by filtering the html retrieved and then render the html elements.

```js
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';
// Clean String From XSS 
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';


export const renderFilteredHTML = string => renderHTML(DOMPurify.sanitize(string));
```